# How I can send liveChange values from Activity to Fragment in Java?

Tags: java, android, fragment, listener, android-livedata

how I can change a TextView in an android fragment by variable of MainActivity. I try to log geographical values (from -> to in miles) and want this result show in a fragment live.

My App has a Viewpager and three fragments. In my MainActivity I have a FloatingAction Button for start tracking and stop tracking. The result will be save in a variable on MainActivity. The fragment is loaded already.

[image]

I think I need a construct like listener for my fragment?

Comment: Can you post your MainActivity and Fragment code which Fragment value change from Main Activity

Comment: You can use shared `ViewModel`. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: i found this : https://blog.usejournal.com/observe-livedata-from-viewmodel-in-fragment-fd7d14f9f5fb is this the best way?